# How do I change Vaadin Label Text color?

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to change the text color of label text in my Vaadin project. I am having a hard time understanding how theming works. I know there are a few methods to do this, but I've had no luck with any. I've tried to create a new style in the css file, and add style by using 'setStyleName' but the color doesn't get applied. I've tried many methods and just can't seem to get it to work. In Firebug I can disable where it says "color: #141414;" below and the text turns white on the web page.

When I Firebug one of the Label elements this is what I see:

```
.evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child h1, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h1, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child h2, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h2, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child h3, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h3, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child h4, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h4, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child h1, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h1, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child h2, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h2, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child h3, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h3, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child h4, .evoltweb .v-verticallayout > div > .v-slot:first-child .v-label-h4 {
margin-top: 16px;
}

.evoltweb h2, .evoltweb .v-label-h2 {
font-size: 1.6em;
letter-spacing: -0.02em;
margin-bottom: 0.77em;
margin-top: 1.6em;
}

.evoltweb h1, .evoltweb .v-label-h1, .evoltweb h2, .evoltweb .v-label-h2, .evoltweb h3, .evoltweb .v-label-h3 {
color: #141414;
font-weight: 200;
line-height: 1.1;
}

h2, *:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section) h1 {
display: block;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: bold;
margin-block-end: 0.83em;
margin-block-start: 0.83em;
}

address, article, aside, blockquote, body, caption, center, col, colgroup, dd, dir, div, dl, dt, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, html, legend, li, listing, main, marquee, menu, nav, noframes, ol, p, plaintext, pre, section, summary, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, ul, xmp {
unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate;
}
```

Inherited from **div.v-label.v-widget.v-has-width**

This is the HTML for the Label from Firebug:

```
<html>
<head>
<body class="v-generated-body v-ff v-ff47 v-ff470 v-gecko v-win" scroll="auto">
<div id="EVOLtWeb-1346167182" class="v-app evoltweb evoltwebui">
<div class="v-ui v-scrollable" tabindex="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div class="v-loading-indicator third v-loading-indicator-wait" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
<div class="v-verticallayout v-layout v-vertical v-widget v-has-width v-has-height" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div class="v-expand" style="padding-top: 86px;">
<div class="v-slot v-slot-header" style="margin-top: -86px;">
<div class="v-horizontallayout v-layout v-horizontal v-widget header v-horizontallayout-header v-has-width v-has-height" style="width: 100%; height: 46px;">
<div class="v-expand" style="padding-left: 486px;">
<div class="v-slot" style="margin-left: -486px;">
<div class="v-spacing"></div>
<div class="v-slot v-align-middle">
<div class="v-spacing"></div>
<div class="v-slot v-slot-sp-gray v-align-right v-align-middle" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="v-widget -sp-gray v-has-width v-has-height sp-gray v-widget-sp-gray" style="width: 100%; height: 0px;">
<div class="v-sliderpanel-wrapper mode-top layout-horizontal flow-in-content sp-gray">
<div class="v-sliderpanel-content sp-gray" style="display: block; height: 631px;">
<div class="v-verticallayout v-layout v-vertical v-widget v-has-width v-margin-top v-margin-right v-margin-bottom v-margin-left" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="v-slot">
<div class="v-slot">
<div class="v-label v-widget v-has-width" style="width: 100%;">
<h2>1) Getting Started with EVOLt </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

This is Vaadin code from my project for the labels:

```
public void paintLayout() { 

        Label sliderHtml = new Label(String.format("<h1>EVOLT Help Center</h1>"),ContentMode.HTML);
        addComponent(sliderHtml);   
        Label label1 = new Label(("<h2>1) Getting Started with EVOLt</h2>"), ContentMode.HTML);
        addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener() {

            public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {
                if (event.getChildComponent() == label1) {
                    System.out.println("clicked Label1");
                    removeAllComponents();
                    Label sliderHtml = new Label(String.format("<h3>Getting Started with EVOLT</h3>"),ContentMode.HTML);
                    addComponent(sliderHtml);
                    Resource mainHelpImage = new ClassResource("evolt_with_arrows_small.png");
                    addComponent(sliderHtml);
```

I need label1, and sliderHtml text colored white. Right now it is black. Can anyone tell me the easiest way to make my label text White instead of Black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out one way to do it:

```
Label label1 = new Label(
String.format("<font size = \"5\" color=\"white\"> MyText" )
, ContentMode.HTML);
```

Adding the above HTML ContentMode and appropriate HTML made the text white, but I had to add it to each element one by one.

Thanks. :)

Comment: It's rather strange, what you do with vaadin. Usually you don't write HTML and/or CSS directly in the java code. Usually you use the addStyleName(...) to the components and style them via the sass logic

Comment: I tried this, but could not get the color applied when adding the CSS to the stylesheet.  I tried adding this in CSS: .whiteLabelText {
   color: #FFFFFF; } and to the class I add this:  label.setStyleName("whiteLabelText");  recompile theme and the white color does not get applied. It stays black.

Comment: It's a good idea to use the addStyleName() instead of setStyleName(), the setXXX method clears all other styles (Which is usually not what you wish). Probably your scss was not correct

Comment: Easier syntax to use the single-quote marks rather than double-quote marks, around the `5` and the `white`. Both are accepted HTML & CSS. No need for escapes. I verified this works in Vaadin 8.1.3. Like this: `new Label( String.format("<font size = '5'  color='white'> Invalid" ) , ContentMode.HTML)`